# Laravel how to use blade code in Javascript var?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm making simple chat modal box with JavaScript.

```
    @section('content')
<div id="shoutbox" class="widget widget-shouts">
    <div class="chat-messages">
    <ul class="messages list-unstyled">
        <?php for($i = sizeof($shouts) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
            $shout = $shouts[$i]; ?>
            @if ($shout->creator->avatar)
<a href="/players/{!! $shout->creator->slug !!}"><img class="img-responsive user-photo @if ($shout->creator->isOnline())user-on @else user-off @endif" src="/uploads/users/{!! $shout->creator->avatar !!}"></a>
@else
<a href="/players/{!! $shout->creator->slug !!}"><img class="img-responsive user-photo @if ($shout->creator->isOnline())user-on @else user-off @endif" src="/img/default/no_user-150.png"></a>
@endif
            <li>
<span class="text">
@if ($shout->creator->userRights() == 'SADMIN')
<div class="comments-rights"><div class="users-sadmin">OWNER</div></div>
@endif
@if ($shout->creator->userRights() == 'ADMIN')
<div class="comments-rights"><div class="users-admin">ADMIN</div></div>
@endif
@if ($shout->creator->userRights() == 'VIP')
<div class="comments-rights"><div class="users-vip">VIP</div></div>
@endif
<span class="chat-username"><a href="/players/{!! $shout->creator->slug !!}">{!! $shout->creator->username !!}</a></span>
    <span class="chat-date">
{!! $shout->created_at->dateTime() !!}</span>
@if (user()->hasAccess('comments', PERM_DELETE) or $shout->creator->id == user()->id)
    <span class="chat-actions">
<a href="/shouts/delete/{!! $shout->id !!}" aria-label="Ištrinti pokalbio komentarą" data-balloon-pos="left"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
</span>
@endif
<br /> {!! $shout->text !!}
</span>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
                @endsection
            @yield('content')
```

This is my all balde shoutbox script without JavaScript and AJAX.
How can i call it on JavaScript?
I'm trying todo like that:

```
var $message = '@yield('content')';
```

Cuz i need to reload messages with is "@section('content')". But nothing. I'm new on laravel don't be really mad on me! And thanks for helping. I know my code looks stupid, but i'm just testing and learning :) Thanks again!

Comment: Your template has new lines in it. New lines are forbidden in JS string literals.

Comment: @Quentin so i need to make all it in one line?

Comment: This could be fixed by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Are you sure, you want to return JavaScript from the server that has a whole HTML string inside a variable?